# iOS 8: Does "Allow full access" allows the developer to access keystrokes from other keyboards?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, privacy

This "allow full access" setting is widely discussed, but I cannot manage to find any clear answer on this.

According to the [technical specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html), allowing full access grants, among other, "Ability to send keystrokes and other input events for server-side processing".

However, these so-called "keystrokes" are unclear IMHO.
Are they the keystrokes typed within the keyboard App only, or all keystrokes typed with any keyboard?

Let's say that I have two keyboard KA and KB, with full access granted for both.
The container app for both KA and KB can logically access their respective keystrokes and do whatever they want with them.

But can KA access the keystrokes typed in KB?

Thanks!

[EDIT 14.10.09]

[WDUK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1391713/wduk)'s answer clears up the relationship between host apps and their extensions.

But the [general KB documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html) refers to "keystrokes" without ever (?) mentioning whether these keystrokes are limited to the keyboard extension they were typed within.

Although it seems obvious, what bothers me is that I cannot find any clear statement, especially since the iOS warning states "*[...] anything you type, including things you previously typed with this keyboard*". The **mention** "*anything you type*" **plus the precision** "*including [...] with this keyboard*" rings a bell to me.

A more statisfying warning would be  "*[...] anything you type **with this keyboard**, including previous keystrokes*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Allow full access" enables a keyboard extension to talk to it's host application, and visa versa.

For example, if I have my `KeyboardApp`, and this provides a `Keyboard` extension:

- Allow Full Access: `KeyboardApp` is able to view data generated by the `Keyboard` extension, and send data back to the extension.

  For example, if I type in `"Stac"`, `Keyboard` sends this to `KeyboardApp`, `KeyboardApp` can perform a web request, and then recognize that this should mean `"StackOverflow"`. `KeyboardApp` sends that result back to `Keyboard` to autocomplete.
- Without Full Access: `KeyboardApp` cannot talk to `Keyboard`, and visa versa. This means the application cannot provide additional support to the extension; the extension has to do all the hard work.

  For example: The ability to swipe between keys to type doesn't need `KeyboardApp` to work, that functionality can be fully contained within the extension. This means it would work without "Allow Full Access" being enabled. Any fancy autocomplete though would not be possible, as `Keyboard` would need to talk to `KeyboardApp` to get that information (because `Keyboard` doesn't have internet access)

This is a very basic example, but demonstrates the point. Also, an extension can only communicate with it's host application, it cannot talk to other applications directly. This means other keyboards and their respective host apps cannot snoop on data typed using a keyboard that's not their own.

Apple does have documentation regarding this in the App Extension Programming Guide. There are two areas you should look at, firstly is how App Extensions work (and how they can't talk to other applications directly): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2

And also information regarding custom keyboards and Allow Full Access (with the key for Full Access being `RequestsOpenAccess`): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! This confirms my suspicions. Anyway I can't find any place where it is clearly stated that host apps can only access keystrokes from within their kb extension...

Comment: I've updated the answer with information regarding Apple's documentation on the subject

Comment: Thanks for the fast update! This clears up the relationship between host apps and their extensions...But the general KB documentation  refers to "keystrokes" without ever (?) mentioning whether these keystrokes are limited to the keyboard extension they were typed within. Although it seems obvious, what bothers me is that I cannot find any clear statement, especially since the iOS warning states "[...] anything you type, including things you previously typed with this keyboard". The mention "anything you type" plus the precision "including [...] with this kb" rings a bell to me.

Comment: Edited to question to be more specific :)

Comment: The keyboard extension provides the view (`UIInputView`) for the custom keyboard, and the extension is the only one who can listen to touch events on that view. "Keystrokes" in this context means "touches within the UIInputView of the keyboard extension". "Anything you type, including things previously typed" means that the extension can (but doesn't have to) keep a log of what you've typed, and share with it's host app. I'm not sure if I can make this point clearer; extensions are an extension of the host app, and cannot be globally observed by others.